# Regular expression to check word and word length

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript I am using the regular expression `/^([a-z]){3}^(foo)/i` to try and match a specific word and the word's length. The regex should also be case insensitive. So I added an `i` modifier on the end.

What I think this says it should do is

```
^          : Start at beginning of string
([a-z]){3} : Match [a-z] exactly three times
^          : Go back to start of string
(foo)      : Match the word foo exactly
```

However when I tested this with the following strings `fOo`, `foo`, `Foo`, `FoO` it didn't return any matches.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain what I am doing wrong and help me fix it.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vL7xQ8/1)

**Edit for Sukima**

Example strings which should work:

```
fOo
FoO
foo
FOO
```

Example string which shouldn't work

```
f o o
adfsFoO
fooFoe
FfOoF
:fdFoo:
```

The aim of the regex is to check that the string matches the word `foo` exactly and is length of `3` exactly.

Comment: you mean `^([a-z]){3}|^(foo)` ? demo https://regex101.com/r/vL7xQ8/2

Comment: [`/^([a-z]){3}^|(foo)$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/vL7xQ8/3)

Comment: That's not how `^` works. A lookahead might be better.

Comment: Thank you. That fixes it

Comment: Why don't you just do `/^foo$/`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hence `foo` actually is a subset of your prior regex, the following should do the trick:

```
/^\w{3})/i
```

or one of the following if numbers are not allowed:

```
/^[a-z]{3}/i
/^[A-a]{3}/
```

This regex matches every word of exactly three characters at the beginning of the string (or line if you specify the /m modifier) regardless if its upper- or lowercase.

#### Edit (responds to comment):

if you need to match the word foo precisely regardless of its case just go for:

```
/^foo$/i
```

Example matches: `fOo`, `fOo`, `foo`, `Foo`, `FoO`... more available on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vL7xQ8/4)

Comment: I was using two patterns because it has to match a certain word and the string can only contain that word, hence the length pattern. Thank you for the answer though

Comment: Use `/^[a-z]{3}/i` instead of `/^[a-zA-Z]{3}/i` ;).

Comment: @shA.t it was meant to be a modifier-less solution; i fixed the typo and added both alternatives, thanks ;)

Comment: what's wrong with doing `/^[A-z]{3}/` (leaving out the case insensitive qualifier)?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. just updated the answer ;) @ganders

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues in that regexp. First the `^` means start of line which is meaningless unless it is the first character in the regexp pattern.

Second the pattern `[a-z]{3}` will match `foo` anyway so the second pattern is just noise.

Think what you want is simply `^[a-z]{3}` which will match `foo` in `foo` and `foobar`.

As an aside if you want to match more than one pattern at start (or end) of line then you have to separate the patterns with a pipe `|`.

`^foo|^bar` will match `foo` and `bar`, but not `bazbar` or `bazfoo`.

Comment: I was using two patterns because it has to match a certain word and the string can only contain that word, hence the length pattern. Thank you for the answer though

Comment: Show an example text you want to search and the actual result you want. Then others can better recommend a regexp pattern that will work and explain why.

Comment: I updated the question. I hope it makes it more clear on what I am trying to achieve